# How can I play GTA roleplay on PS5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, ps5

I have GTA 5 premium edition, also GTA online. I heard that GTA 5 roleplay is modded PC version and not playable on PlayStation but with the help of a Roleplay Discord server I joined, I heard you can play it on PlayStation 4 and 5 as well. I tried to search for the proper step but don't know how to do it on PlayStation 5.

How can I do this on PS5?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I think it'll highly likely require them to be hacked. Why not ask in that Discord first?

Comment: I don't use discord but I will try.

Comment: You mean FiveM? https://fivem.net/

Comment: I followed this channel instructions and currently stuck on training part, they will sent me invite on training time 
https://discord.com/channels/934204612779573329/962757149862281236